# How to save a Holt model forecast in a dataframe in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, holtwinters

I have sample data in following format [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TN563.png)and I am trying to run Holts model on it to forecast ln_value for future 10 time points for each groupby variable 'bid'. I am running following snippet but I am unable to store the forecast in a dataframe. Can someone please help on how to do it? Thanks

def triple_smoothing(g):
print(f'Creating model for: {g.bid.iloc[0]}')

```
model = ExponentialSmoothing(g['ln_val'],trend='add', seasonal=None, damped_trend=True)

fit = model.fit()
fit.summary()
# Forecast
prediction_size = 10
forecast_values = fit.forecast(prediction_size)
print(forecast_values)
print()
```

df.groupby('bid').apply(triple_smoothing)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5xBh.png)
is what I am expecting in the dataframe

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.